# Button writes to EditText

Tags: android, button, layout, android-edittext

I want to make some buttons that write a letter to an  EditText. My java code:

```
package com.koostamas.keyboard;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button buttona;
EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttona = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttona);

    buttona.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttona.getText();

}

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Button buttona = (Button)v;
        editText.setText(editText.getText().toString()+buttona.getText().toString());


    }
}
```

My layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonb"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttona"
    android:text="@string/buttonb"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttona"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/buttona"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="58"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:inputType="text" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It doesn't work and I don't know why. I found this solution on the Internet and I'm not an expert. Could you write me clearly how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add the logcat output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take reference of `EditText` id in the `onCreate()`:

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Comment: Thanks, it was my big,big fault.